# My Java Spring Project build successfully but in the log give me error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I have java spring project. When I build the Project, project build successfully but in the log give me this error: - java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. Тhe project is working properly. But I want to remove this error in the log when I build the project

Shows me that the problem is in this row in Application.java -
SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

This is my Application.java

```
package com.zetcode;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Resource
    protected ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Resource
    protected SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver(){
        final ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"thyme/*"});
        viewResolver.setExcludedViewNames(new String[] {"jsp/*"});
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine);
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver(){
        final InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        viewResolver.setViewNames("jsp/*");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver(){
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(0);
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver jspTemplateResolver(){
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

This is the log

```
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:309) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:278) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:229) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-jasper-9.0.1.jar:9.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:370) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:106) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.zetcode.Application.main(Application.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor27.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\svetl\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.3-1\jaxb1-impl.jar
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1842) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1160) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:719) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:239) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:169) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:346) ~[na:na]
    ... 51 common frames omitted

2021-07-02 19:50:03.839  INFO 15960 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2021-07-02 19:50:03.849  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-07-02 19:50:03.850  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1918 ms
2021-07-02 19:50:03.874  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2021-07-02 19:50:03.878  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2021-07-02 19:50:03.878  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2021-07-02 19:50:03.878  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2021-07-02 19:50:03.878  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2021-07-02 19:50:03.916  WARN 15960 --- [           main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2021-07-02 19:50:04.196  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-07-02 19:50:04.703  INFO 15960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-02 19:50:04.706  INFO 15960 --- [           main] com.zetcode.Application                  : Started Application in 3.134 seconds (JVM running for 3.587)
```

Comment: Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680199/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **disable** the embedded tomcat manifest scanning.

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
   return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
      @Override
      protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
         ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
   }};
}
```

Original source: [how to disable tomcat manifest scanning with spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481466/how-to-disable-tomcat-manifest-scanning-with-spring-boot)

Comment: The link you provided has now gotten an update for Springboot 1.5.2, where this is now a controllable property. Just add
`server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=*.jar` to your application.properties